# Calculating refractionindex of water given permittivity

Tags: electromagnetism, optics

I'm a bit confused. The refraction index is calculated by

$$n=\frac{c}{v},\tag1$$

where $c$ is the lightspeed and $v$ is the phasevelocity of light in the medium of interest, water in this case.

In my book they say that

> The permittivity of water at optical frequencies is $1.75\epsilon_0$.
>   Thus the index of refraction for water is $n_w=\sqrt{1.75}\approx
>  1.32.$

Can someone explain why this is? They are not even using $(1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The phase velocity of electromagnetic radiation, expressed in terms of the bulk electromagnetic parameters of the material, [is
given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permittivity#Relative_permittivity)
$$
v^2=\frac{1}{\mu\epsilon}=\frac{1}{\mu_r\epsilon_r}\frac{1}{\mu_0\epsilon_0}=
\frac{c^2}{\mu_r\epsilon_r}
$$
from which it immediately follows that
$$
\frac{c}{v}:= n =\sqrt{\mu_r\epsilon_r}
$$
which simplifies to $\sqrt{\epsilon_r}$ for non-magnetic materials.

Comment: Thanks! The simplification to $\sqrt{\epsilon_r}$, is it because for non-magnetic media we have that $\mu = \mu_0$ so that $$\mu_r = \frac{\mu}{\mu_0}=\frac{\mu_0}{\mu_0}=1=$$

Comment: @Parseval yes presumably water at optical frequencies has $\mu=\mu_0$ so $\mu_r=1$.